# Writing similar contents to many files at once in C++

Tags: c++, io

I am working on a C++ program that needs to write several hundreds of ASCII files. These files will be almost identical. In particular, the size of the files is always exactly the same, with only few characters different between them.

For this I am currently opening up N files with a for-loop over fopen and then calling fputc/fwrite on each of them for every chunk of data (every few characters). This seems to work, but it feels like there should be some more efficient way.

Is there something I can do to decrease the load on the file system and/or improve the speed of this? For example, how taxing is it on the file system to keep hundreds of files open and write to all of them bit by bit? Would it be better to open one file, write that one entirely, close it and only then move on to the next?

Comment: That all entirely depends on your OS, settings, used filesystem and probably many more. In the end the data will need to be written these multiple times anyways, unless you have a filesystem that can reuse blocks.

Comment: Are these files for a webserver or something like that? If so, how about dynamically generating the content when requested instead?

Comment: No, they need to be generated ahead unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some testing now and it seems like, at least on my system, writing all files in parallel is about 60% slower than writing them one after the other (263s vs. 165s for 100 files times 100000000 characters).

I also tried to use ofstream instead of fputc, but fputc seems to be about twice as fast.

In the end, I will probably keep doing what I am doing at the moment, since the complexity of rewriting my code to write one file at a time is not worth the performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the cost of context switches usually involved on doing any of those syscalls then yes, you should "pigghy back" as much data is possible taing into account the writing time and the lenght of buffers.

Given also the fact that this is primarly an io driven problem maybe a pub sub architecture where the publisher bufferize data for you to give to any subscriber that does the io work (and that also waits for the underlying storage mechanism to be ready) could be a good choice.

Comment: I was under the impression that fputc actually had some sort of internal buffer, so that not every call to fputc would actually result in the character being written to disk. Is this not the case?

Comment: every time you call a function you have that overhead, anyway you can control the buffer type of your stream (man setbuf).

Answer (score 1):

You can write just once to one file and then make copies of that file. You can read about how making copies [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

This is the sample code from the upper link how to do it in C++:

```
int main() {
    String* path = S"c:\\temp\\MyTest.txt";
    String* path2 = String::Concat(path, S"temp");

    // Ensure that the target does not exist.
    File::Delete(path2);

    // Copy the file.
    File::Copy(path, path2);
    Console::WriteLine(S"{0} copied to {1}", path, path2);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about the characters that differ between the files? And that looks like c# (not c++).

Comment: @hmjd If he particulary knows which characters he should change, he can manually do it. As said by OP "only few characters". Chech the link if u are not sure whether it is C# or C++

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was actually considering something like this at some point (copy the same file many times, then edit the files using fseek and fputc), but it seems a bit "dangerous" since you need to translate between position in the file and position in your string. But if the other approach doesn't work out I might revisit this!

Comment: @Nils yeah, that might end up messy, but again you might try using some tricks, mb some char flags identifying the values you have to modify...

Comment: even if this actually is C++, it certainly doesn't look like it is. in C++ you would use a std::string, not obscure String*. This looks like a microsoft Windows only solution which is fairly bad.

Answer (score 1):

Without benchmarking your particular system, I would GUESS - and that is probably as best as you can get - that writing a file at a time is better than opening lost of files and writing the data to several files. After all, preparing the data in memory is a minor detail, the writing to the file is the "long process".